# Skip Identity number in Entity Framework 6 code first seed

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have an enum which has the numbers 0,1,2,4.
I would like to add them to the table but I always get 0,1,2,3 in the identity column.

I add them using AddOrUppdate in the seed section.

Can I set the identity to what I want instead to what the database seems to set it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] as attribute on the primary key propertyname.
After that I could set the identity to what I wanted.